# Vue - Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, css, apache, vue.js, vue-cli

I've deployed two Vue JS Apps on production (Apache2 server), one with lazy-load components and the other without lazy load.

When I try to directly open a different URL (route) from the base url `/` the project without lazy-load works fine, however, the app with lazy load don't work as expected, it shows this error on the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://my.exampleapp/css/app.e5de818b.css".

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://my.exampleapp/css/chunk-vendors.54e65764.css".
```

Generated HTML:

```
<link href=/css/app.e5de818b.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=/css/chunk-vendors.54e65764.css rel=preload as=style>
```

Is there any configuration I need to add on apache2 or it is something to configure on my Vue App?